# How to replace POSIXct values with numeric?

Tags: r

i'm fairly new to R

i have these values:

```
> results$batterydate[file_i]
[1] "2014-05-20 EDT"
> L[[13]]
[1] 1400558400
```

I'm trying to do:

```
results$batterydate[file_i] <- L[[13]]
```

But end up with this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I'm just trying to replace the value in results$batterydate[file_i] with L[[13]], what's going on?

Comment: `results$batterydate` is a vector of class `POSIXct`. You can't assign something of one class (your numeric 1400558400) to vector of a different class, so R tries to convert the numeric to POSIXct. But to do that, you need to supply an `origin` date.

Comment: It seems like more than a coincidence that the numeric you're trying to assign happens to be the same date as what's already there (when converted with the usual origin in Eric Fail's answer). Maybe you just want to convert your whole column to numeric? `results$batterydate = as.numeric(results$batterydate)`?

Comment: ya the numbers should be different later on...

Comment: your approach works though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
results$batterydate[file_i] <- as.POSIXct(L[[13]],origin="1970-01-01")
```

`1400558400` is `2014-05-20 06:00:00 CEST` in `POSIXct`, i.e.,

```
as.POSIXct(1400558400,origin="1970-01-01")
```

you can use `unclass()` to extract the raw value, if that's what you are looking to do,

```
(z <- Sys.time()) 
#> [1] "2018-02-02 21:45:47 CET"
unclass(z) 
#> [1] 1517604347
```

if you can provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question we can work from it would be possible to show specifically how it might be possible to solve your issue.

Comment: no errors, but results$batterydate[file_i] is still "2014-05-20 EDT"

Comment: should be the value of L[[13]]

Comment: the value of `L[[13]]`, `1400558400`, is `2014-05-20 EDT` in POSIXct, that's why I also showed you the `unclass()`. You can get `1400558400` simply by unclassing `results$batterydate[file_i]`.